# helixtoolkit (BEPU?) physics object

Tags: c#

I need a help with creating physics object for PLC. I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll2ue0mrSTc) video on YouTube.

I tried to contact the author for the source code, but I was not able to.

I would like to make a line with models from Solidworks which will be added to helix toolkit.

Is there anyone here who is able to help me with my problem?

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can anyone help me" not an actual question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going to [the solidworks forum](http://forum.solidworks.com) for help.